# Replace spaces in QString with backslash spaces

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qstring

I need to replace spaces in a QString with backslash spaces.

I have: `QString myPath = /home/matt/my file.txt`

I need: `QString myPath = /home/matt/my\ file.txt`

I tried using `myPath.replace(" ", "\ ");` but unfortunately the compiler interrupts this as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler uses `\` as an escape character in strings. You will need two backslashes.

```
myPath.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```