# MAC - QString replace spaces with backslash spaces

Tags: macos, qt, replace, qstring

Firstly, i have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033583/replace-spaces-in-qstring-with-backslash-spaces).

I'm currently using Qt 5.8 on Mac, and tried below codes:

```
QString test("/Users/test/Documents/ASCII Tables.pdf");
qDebug() << test.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

expected result shoud be like:

```
"/Users/test/Documents/ASCII\ Tables.pdf"
```

what i got is two blackslashes are added:

```
"/Users/test/Documents/ASCII\\ Tables.pdf"
```

Anyone has suggestion?

---

**Update:** (regarding to @docsteer's answer) i intended to use the `QString test` as part of `QProcess:start()`, for example:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("ls " + test);
process.waitForFinished(-1);
qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << process.readAllStandardError();
```

and the result is not as expected, as both backslashes are inserted into the command:

```
""
"ls: /Users/test/Documents/ASCII\\: No such file or directory\nls: Tables.pdf: No such file or directory\n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing there is not the actual content of the string. QDebug escapes the characters as it prints them:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-16

> Normally, QDebug prints the string inside quotes and transforms
>   non-printable characters to their Unicode values (\u1234).
>
> To print non-printable characters without transformation, enable the
>   noquote() functionality.

If you change your code to

```
qDebug().noquote() << test.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

You will see what you expect - the raw content of the string

Comment: hi, thanks for the notice, but i updated the question, maybe another suggestion? ^_^

Comment: OK, so that's a bit of an extension to the original question. I don't have a Mac handy to try this, but I suspect you need to use QProcess with arguments instead of putting it all in the command. Try: `QProcess process;QStringList arguments;arguments << test;process.setProgram("ls");process.setArguments(arguments);`

Comment: oh yeah, it turns out when calling `process` with `program` and `arguments` we don't need to convert spaces to backslash spaces... thanks a lot